# bar with different colors

Tags: charts, google-visualization

i have one table with 2 column and  3 rows (encours | 15 ; gele|10 ; clos|14)
and i'm using google chart bar 
the probleme is i want ti use different color for the bars 
whene i'm using this 
 colors: ['red','yellow', 'blue'],
all bars are only red , and i don't want that 
i hope you understand me , you will find my code below

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var options = {
            title: 'Graph Evolution (ticket encours/clos)',
            width: 1200,
            height: 800,
            bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
            seriesType: 'bars',
            series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
            colors: ['red','yellow', 'blue'],
        };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "multicolumn.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);

             chart.draw(data, options);
            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }
        });

            }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `colors` option assigns each color in the array to each series in the data table.
where the series is a column in the data table, following the x-axis.

for example, in order to have 3 colors (using the `colors` option),
you will need have 3 columns in the data table, besides the x-axis, or first column.

e.g.

```
x,        encours, gele, clos
category, 15,      10,   14
```

instead, you only have one series...

```
x,       category
encours, 15
gele,    10
clos,    14
```

as such, the `colors` option will not work.
we need to use a [style column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#stylerole) instead.

this allows us to assign the color in the data table...

```
x,       category, style
encours, 15,       red
gele,    10,       yellow
clos,    14,       blue
```

you can include the colors in your data,
for the style column, use object notation for the column heading...

```
[
  ['category', 'value', {type: 'string', role: 'style'}],
  ['encours', 15, 'red'],
  ['gele', 10, 'yellow'],
  ['clos', 14, 'blue'],
]
```

or we can use a data view, with a calculated column for the style role.

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([
  0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var category = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      var color;
      switch (category) {
        case 'encours':
          color = 'red';
          break;

        case 'gele':
          color = 'yellow';
          break;

        case 'clos':
          color = 'blue';
          break;
      }
      return color;
    },
    type: 'string',
    role: 'style'
  }
]);
```

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var options = {
        title: 'Graph Evolution (ticket encours/clos)',
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        series: { 5: { type: 'line' } },
        colors: ['red','yellow', 'blue'],
    };


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "multicolumn.aspx/GetChartData",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

            view.setColumns([
              0, 1, {
                calc: function (dt, row) {
                  var category = dt.getValue(row, 0);
                  var color;
                  switch (category) {
                    case 'encours':
                      color = 'red';
                      break;

                    case 'gele':
                      color = 'yellow';
                      break;

                    case 'clos':
                      color = 'blue';
                      break;
                  }
                  return color;
                },
                type: 'string',
                role: 'style'
              }
            ]);

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#chart_div")[0]);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}
```

---

**NOTE:** you should not be using the old version of google charts.
you need to [update](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code) to the newer version.

this will only change the `load` statements.

remove the following script from your page...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

and replace with...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

for the load statements, remove these lines...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

and replace with these...

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Comment: it's not working .. there is error in viwe.setcolumn

Comment: WhiteHat are you here i need your help , hope you see this